# Setting listbox value with different value and label upon page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I am trying to set form value upon page load in a dropdown listbox which loads value thru an ajax call. I was suggested the use of addOption in another thread for a different problem but unfortunately that option does not work for me because data id and data name are different in this case and I only get data Id when the form is rendered. I have noticed addOption code gets executed before the ajax request sends data back.

Following are code snippets from the project. Is there a way to set the value after ajax request is complete?

**HTML**

```
<select name="country" placeholder="Please Select Country  ..."></select>
```

**Data population, JavaScript code**

```
$('[name="country"]').selectize({
    valueField: 'id',
    labelField: 'name',
    searchField: 'name',
    preload: true,
    create: false,
    render: {
        option: function(item, escape) {
            return '<div>' + escape(item['name']) + '</div>';
        }
    },

    load: function(query, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/countrydata',
            type: 'GET',
            error: function() {
                callback();
            },
            success: function(res) {
                callback(res);
            }
        });
    },
});
```

**Data returned by Ajax call**

```
id name
1  USA
2  China
3  Japan
```

Following is my **value setting code** which I want to work

```
$('[name="country"]').selectize();
$('[name="country"]')[0].selectize.setValue(3);
```

Had the valueField and labelField be the same, I could have used following addOption method as suggested in another post but as I am only getting Id upon form render, I cannot use the following code.

```
var item  = {};
item.id   = countryName;
item.name = countryName;

$('[name="country"]')[0].selectize.addOption(item);
```

Comment: Hi. The data returned from your AJAX has that exactly format you posted in your question? Like columns. Or is it a JSON response?

Comment: I've written this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awrffv2m/) with a simple mockup of the AJAX request using JSON and it seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use load method to set options via selectize.js [programmatic API](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md#methods_other). Consider calling `clear()` and `clearOptions()` methods to reset selected values and old options as well.

For simplification purposes only, let's give our input an id:

```
<select id="country" name="country" placeholder="Please Select Country  ..."></select>
```

Assuming the AJAX response is:

```
id name
1  USA
2  China
3  Japan
```

Which is equal to having:

```
var responseText = "id name\n1  USA\n2  China\n3  Japan"
```

Let's split the value, and reformat it into a object selectize likes:

```
var selectizeContent = [];
// Every line will have one value:
responseText.split('\n').forEach(function(line){
    // split current line to id and value:
    var parts = line.split(' ');
    // Verify that ID is numeric, to skip the first line:
    if(!isNaN(parseInt(parts[0]))){
        selectizeContent.push({
            value: parts[0],
            text: parts[1]
        });
    }
});
```

And then once we have `selectizeContent` ready:

```
// Using the ID we gave the select, or any other selector:
var selectize = $("#country")[0].selectize;
selectize.clear();
selectize.clearOptions();
selectize.load(function(callback) {
    callback(selectizeContent);
});
```

Perform everything we just did inside your Ajax callback, and I expect it'll work.

---

`selectizeContent` should be an array of objects that have properties configured in `valueField` and `labelField` options when select was initialized. For example, here is how `selectizeContent` should look like with default `valueField` and `labelField` options:

```
var inviteList = [
    {
        text: 'USA',
        value: 1
    },
    {
        text: 'China',
        value: 2
    },
    {
        text: 'Japan',
        value: 3
    }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function based on the source code of `selectize.js`

```
function setSelectizeValue(selector, value){
    var select = $(selector)[0].selectize;
    // from the lines 1731-1737 of selectize.js
    select.lastQuery = null;
    select.setTextboxValue("");
    select.addItem(value);
    select.setActiveOption(select.getOption(value));
}
```

eg.

**HTML**

```
<select name="country" placeholder="Please Select Country  ..."></select>
<br/>
<button id="select-usa">Select USA</button>
<button id="select-china">Select China</button>
<button id="select-japan">Select Japan</button>
```

**JS**

```
$('[name="country"]').selectize({
    valueField: 'id',
    labelField: 'name',
    searchField: 'name',
    preload: true,
    create: false,
    render: {
      option: function(item, escape) {
        return '<div>' + escape(item['name']) + '</div>';
      }
    },

    load: function(query, callback) {
        var res = [{"id":1,"name":"USA"},{"id":2,"name":"China"},{"id":3,"name":"Japan"}];
        callback(res);
    },
  });

$("#select-usa").click(function(ev){
    setSelectizeValue('[name="country"]',1);
});
$("#select-china").click(function(ev){
    setSelectizeValue('[name="country"]',2);
});
$("#select-japan").click(function(ev){
    setSelectizeValue('[name="country"]',3);
});
```

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davcs86/pLjgh6j0/1/)